# How to read a file where one column data is present in other column using Talend Data Integration

Tags: csv, etl, talend

I get data from a CSV format daily.

Example data looks like:

```
Emp_ID     emp_leave_id           EMP_LEAVE_reason             Emp_LEAVE_Status  Emp_lev_apprv_cnt

 E121          E121-         21 Head ache, fever, stomach-ache    Approved            16

 E139          E139_         5 Attending a marraige of my cousin  Approved            03
```

Here you can see that `emp_leave_id` and `EMP_LEAVE_reason` column data is shifted/scattered into the next columns.

So the problem by using tFileInputDelimited and various reading patterns I couldn't load data correctly into my target database. Mainly I'm not able to read the data correctly with that component in Talend.

Is there a way that I can properly parse this CSV to get my data in the format that I want?

Comment: I'm not sure if I've tidied up your example data properly here and it might be better to post a link to a screenshot of the data in Excel (or some other spreadsheet program) or post the direct text into a code block rather than trying to format it. It would also be good to see a screenshot of how you have configured your tFileInputDelimited component.

Comment: So your direct text might look like `Emp_ID,emp_leave_id,EMP_LEAVE_reason,Emp_LEAVE_Status,Emp_lev_apprv_cnt`

Comment: If you can't fix your input data example we can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a TSV file. Not sure about Talend, but [uniVocity](http://www.univocity.com/pages/about-univocity) can parse these files for you:

```
TsvDataStoreConfiguration tsv = new TsvDataStoreConfiguration("my_TSV_datastore");
tsv.setLimitOfRowsLoadedInMemory(10000);
tsv.addEntities("/some/dir/with/your_files", "ISO-8859-1"); //all files in the given directory path will accessible entities.

JdbcDataStoreConfiguration database = new JdbcDataStoreConfiguration("my_Database", myDataSource);
database.setLimitOfRowsLoadedInMemory(10000);

Univocity.registerEngine(new EngineConfiguration("My_ETL_Engine", tsv, database));
DataIntegrationEngine engine = Univocity.getEngine("My_ETL_Engine");

DataStoreMapping dataStoreMapping = engine.map("my_TSV_datastore", "my_Database");
EntityMapping entityMapping = dataStoreMapping.map("your_TSV_filename", "some_database_table");
entityMapping.identity().associate("Emp_ID", "emp_leave_id").toGeneratedId("pk_leave"); //assumes your database does not keep the original ids.
entityMapping.value().copy("EMP_LEAVE_reason", "Emp_LEAVE_Status").to("reason", "status"); //just copies whatever you need

engine.executeCycle(); //executes the mapping.
```

Do not use a CSV parser to parse TSV inputs. It won't handle escape sequences properly (such as \t inside the value, you will get the escape sequence instead of a tab character), and will surely break if your value has a quote in it (a CSV parser will try to find the closing quote character and will keep reading chars until it finds another quote)

Disclosure: I am the author of this library. It's open-source and free (Apache V2.0 license).